# Turning off transparency effect on windows 10 taskbar only

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, transparency

Is it possible to turn off transparency effect on only taskbar, leaving this effect on start menu and other "windows"? Because when I turning it off in settings -> personalization -> colors this effect disappears for all menus and bars.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to have transparency separate for Taskbar and other windows.

Right click on Task Bar and select Properties.

In the sub-window that comes up, transparency is not a separate option.

What you might do is set transparency elsewhere as you desire, and then make sure either (a) the taskbar is a different color or shade of color and/or (b) keep the taskbar hidden unless used.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using the standard Windows 10 Start Menu and Taskbar.

Third-party replacement products for the Start Menu may add the ability
of disassociating the general Windows transparency from that of the Taskbar.
Installing them will disable the Windows 10 Start Menu and replace it.

An example is [Open-Shell-Menu](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu).
Transparency of the Taskbar is handled by right-click on the Start Orb,
Setting, and use the Taskbar tab.